# Loading information using Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class that is managing my data model that also contains the code that manages the Hibernate connection to store the data as a SQLite database (using a custom Dialect)

```
@Entity
@Table
public class PFSRegion {

@Id
private String regionName;
private String location;
private ArrayList<Scenario> scenarioList = new ArrayList<Scenario>();
private ArrayList<Venue> venues = new ArrayList<Venue>();
private ArrayList<Player> players = new ArrayList<Player>();
private ArrayList<Session> sessions = new ArrayList<Session>();

//hibernate vars
private Configuration config;
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public PFSRegion(String fileName)
{
    configHibernate(fileName);
    .....
}

...

private void configHibernate(String fileName)
{

    if(!(fileName.endsWith(".rgn")))
    {
        fileName += ".rgn";
    }

    //set up hibernate
    config = new Configuration()
        .addAnnotatedClass(com.philderbeast.paizolib.Event.class)
        .addAnnotatedClass(com.philderbeast.paizolib.Player.class)
        .addAnnotatedClass(com.philderbeast.paizolib.Scenario.class)
        .addAnnotatedClass(com.philderbeast.paizolib.Session.class)
        .addAnnotatedClass(com.philderbeast.paizolib.Venue.class)
        .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect")
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.sqlite.JDBC")
        .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:sqlite:" + fileName)
        .setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");

    sessionFactory = config.buildSessionFactory();
}
```

What I'm looking to do is load the `regionName` and `location` variables in the constructor when I'm loading from an existing database however im not having any success at finding a way of doing this.

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I might tackle this problem by wrapping up the creation of the Hibernate `SessioFactory` by using a helper class, perhaps a `RegionSessionFactory`

```
public class RegionSessionFactory {
  public RegionSessionFactory(String regionName) {
    // construct the Hibernate SessionFactory here
    this.sessionFactory = // construct the Hibernate SessionFactory.
  }
  public String getRegionName() {
    return this.regionName;
  }
  public SessionFactory getHibernateSessionFactory() {
    return this.sessionFactory;
  }
}
```

You may have the need to lookup a particular `RegisionSessionFactory` by name or some other identifier, so you might want to store the instantiated object in some registry-based map class.

That will also allow you to gracefully close all open `SessionFactory` instances at shutdown of your application by iterating them and callling `#getHibernateSessionFactory().close()`.

There is no need to implement a `PFSRegion` instance as an `@Entity` annotated class.  All this code is purely infrastructure related so that you can obtain the Hibernate `Session` and thus query and manipulate the various entities stored within each `RegionSessionFactory`.

Comment: Prehaps I didn't explain the problem as well as I thought, I'm looking to use the constructor to load the PFSRegion object, when parsed a filename that is the SQLite database that contains the object (there will only ever be one PFSRegion per database)

I'm not sure that this is the best way to achieve this, or even a good way to do it.

Comment: It sounds to me like instead you need to spin up multiple `SessionFactory` instances per SQLite database file, but each SQLite database file uses the same entity models, correct?

Comment: Correct each database file uses the same model, but they are for different data sets, only one file will be open at any given time

Comment: I rewrote my answer based on these details, give it a look.